# Implicit differentiation to find the slope of the tangent line to the graph at the indicated point

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I used `ContourPlot` to plot the graph of `x Sin[Pi y] - y Cos[Pi x] == 1` with the following input:

```
eqn[x_, y_] := (x Sin[Pi y] - y Cos[Pi x] )== 1
ContourPlot[Evaluate[eqn[x, y]], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]
```

To find $dy/dx$ I used the following code:

```
yprimeEq = D[eqn[x, y[x]], x];
sol = Solve[yprimeEq, y'[x]] // Simplify;
dydx = y'[x] /. First[sol] /. y[x] -> y;
```

I am stuck on finding the slope of the tangent line to the graph at $(2/3,2)$. I know I have to just plug in $2/3$ for $x$ and $2$ for $y$ but I don't know how to write it in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate your equation :

```
exp00= Dt /@ (x Sin[Pi y] - y Cos[Pi x] == 1) 

 (* -Cos[π x] Dt[y] + π x Cos[π y] Dt[y] + π y Dt[
   x] Sin[π x] + Dt[x] Sin[π y]==0 *)
```

( = $-\text{Cos}[\pi  x] \text{Dt}[y]+\pi  x \text{Cos}[\pi  y] \text{Dt}[y]+\pi  y \text{Dt}[x] \text{Sin}[\pi  x]+\text{Dt}[x] \text{Sin}[\pi  y]==0$)

replace Dt[x] by for example dx, idem for y

```
 exp01 = exp00 /. {Dt[y] -> dy, Dt[x] -> dx}  

(* -dy Cos[π x] + dy π x Cos[π y] + dx π y Sin[π x] +
   dx Sin[π y] == 0 *)
```

( = $-\text{dy} \text{Cos}[\pi  x]+\text{dy} \pi  x \text{Cos}[\pi  y]+\text{dx} \pi  y \text{Sin}[\pi  x]+\text{dx} \text{Sin}[\pi  y]==0$)

The reason for doing this is that if we gives yet numerical values to x and y, Dt[x] and Dt[y] will become null (may be useless here, as we give values at the very end).

Solve dy function of dx :

```
derivative00=dy/dx /. Solve[exp01 ,{dy}][[1]]

(* (-dx π y Sin[π x] - 
 dx Sin[π y])/(dx (-Cos[π x] + π x Cos[π y])) *)
```

( = $\frac{-\text{dx} \pi  y \text{Sin}[\pi  x]-\text{dx} \text{Sin}[\pi  y]}{\text{dx} (-\text{Cos}[\pi  x]+\pi  x \text{Cos}[\pi  y])}$)

Cancel dx which is common to numerator and denominator :

```
derivative01=Cancel[derivative00]

(* (π y Sin[π x] + Sin[π y])/(Cos[π x] - π x Cos[π y]) *)
```

( = $\frac{\pi  y \text{Sin}[\pi  x]+\text{Sin}[\pi  y]}{\text{Cos}[\pi  x]-\pi  x \text{Cos}[\pi  y]}$ )

Apply the numeric values :

```
derivative02=derivative01 /. {x -> 2/3, y -> 2}
```

resultat : `(Sqrt[3] π)/(-(1/2) - (2 π)/3)`

( = $\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2 \pi }{3}}$)

verification :

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[eqn[x, y]], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},
 Epilog -> {
   PointSize[0.03],
   Point[{2/3, 2}],
   Text[Style["{2/3,2}", FontSize -> 12], {2/3, 2}, {1, 1.5}],
   Line[{{2/3 - 1, 
      2 - (Sqrt[3] π)/(-(1/2) - (2 π)/3)}, {2/3 + 1, 
      2 + (Sqrt[3] π)/(-(1/2) - (2 π)/3)}}]
   }]
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot the application of the slash-dot object. Thanks for answering.

Comment: /. is ReplaceAll. Must be used with a rule (->). Exemple : `f[a] /. a->b` gives `f[b]`

Answer (score 1):

Just change the last command to

```
dydx[x_, y_] = (y'[x] /. First[sol] /. y[x] -> y);
```

Comment: you can also just substitute the values: `dydx/.{x->2/3,y->2}`.

Comment: After looking at the outputs from andre's steps I arrived at this. Thanks

Comment: If you want just to find a specific value substituting is enough. If you want to use $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a function of $x,y$ then defining it as a function is better.